# Unable to use service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I created service to do login via social network,
My issue is I am getting error while trying to use it.
my main Component is :

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {UserData} from '../../theme/services/userData';
@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./login.scss')],
  template: require('./login.html'),
})
export class Login {
  constructor(public _userData: UserData) {

  }

  login(form: string) {
    this._userData.login(form);

  }
```

the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFire, AuthProviders} from 'angularfire2';
@Injectable()
export class UserData {
  user = {};
  isAuth = false;

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    debugger;
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => this._changeState(user));
  }
```

the errors are:

> error_handler.js:46 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./Login class Login_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for UserData!ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:46next @ application_ref.js:291schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:81onError @ ng_zone.js:123onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
>   error_handler.js:51 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:51next @ application_ref.js:291schedulerFn @ async.js:89SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:81onError @ ng_zone.js:123onHandleError @ ng_zone_impl.js:65ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113_loop_1 @ zone.js:379drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386
>   error_handler.js:52 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./Login class Login_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for UserData!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all: `No provider for UserData!`

You need to `provide` the `UserData` service in your `app.module.ts` using the `providers` array, like this:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UserData
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered UserData inside the NgModule, into the providers array?